# iPhone SDK "White Flash" transition

Tags: iphone, sdk, transition, fade

I want to make a button; when you press it the screen fades to a "flash of white" and back like in those powerpoint transitions.

I'm thinking maybe dynamically changing the opacity of a white square or something?

What do you think?

Is there something like this that already exists like part of Catransitions or something?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like

```
self.view.alpha = 0.0;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
self.view.alpha = 1.0; 
viewController.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```